# Azure App Service Error while pulling image from ACR using KeyVault (Terraform)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, terraform, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to pull an image from ACR to Azure App Service. I've stored the credentials of ACR on Key Vault. I'm using the endpoint generated by Key Vault in my App Service Terraform Configuration. My TF script looks like this

```
  module "my-ui-service-temp" {
  source                   = "app-service-noconn"
  location                 = "${local.location}"
  name                     = "webapp-temp"
  resource_group_name      = "${module.create-resource-group.name}"
  app_service_plan_id      = "${module.create-app-service-plan.id}"
  app_service_plan_name    = "${module.create-app-service-plan.name}"
  namespace                = "${local.namespace}-temp"
  dotnetframework_version  = "v4.0"
  java_version = "1.8"
  process_32bitworker      = "true"
  websockets_enabled       = "true"
  remote_debugging_enabled = "true"
  local_mysql_enabled      = "true"
  php_version              = "5.5"
  remote_debugging_version = "VS2017"
  tls_version              = "1.2"
  linuxfx_version          = "DOCKER|myregistry.azurecr.io/my-webapp:latest"
  //cors_allowed_origins = "*"

  //ip_address_restriction = "10.198.54.79"

  #ip_address_restriction = "198.203.177.177"
  default_documents      = [ "Default.htm", "Default.html", "Default.asp", "index.htm", "index.html", "iisstart.htm", "default.aspx", "index.php", "hostingstart.html"]

  http2_enabled = "false"
  scm_type      = "none"
  subnet_mask   = "255.255.255.255"

  app_settings {
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL" = "myregistry.azurecr.io"
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME" = "https://myapp-kv-az.vault.azure.net/secrets/my-secret-kv-az/redacted"
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD" = "https://myapp-kv-az.vault.azure.net/secrets/my-pass-az-pass/redacted"
  }

}
```

This is the error I'm getting

> 2019-06-17 16:06:20.651 ERROR - Pulling docker image
>   registry.azurecr.io/myApp-webapp:latest failed: 2019-06-17
>   16:06:20.651 INFO - Pulling image from Docker hub:
>   registry.azurecr.io/myApp-webapp:latest 2019-06-17 16:06:20.676 ERROR
>   - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get
>   https://registry.azurecr.io/v2/myApp-webapp/manifests/latest:
>   unauthorized: authentication required"}
>
> 2019-06-17 16:06:20.687 ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image
>   configuration and credentials (if using private repository)

If, I'm passing my ACR Credentials directly without KeyVault, I'm able to pull the image and build it without any issues. I'm assuming its something to do with Key Vault Access policies.

But, the error message says - Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://registry.azurecr.io/v2/myApp-webapp/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required"}, which is bothering me!

I'm passing the authentication details through keyvault, but App Service is not able to authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it. Instead of passing @Microsoft.keyvault(SecretUri="").

I've used

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "myacrServer" { 
name = "myApp-acr-server-az" 
vault_uri = "myApp-kv-az-acr.vault.azure.net" 
}
```

And then in the app_settings of web app service, I'm passing in that data secret value.

```
app_settings { 
"DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME" = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.myacrusname.value}" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use reference to key vault you can use the [official way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) of doing that. so it would look like this:

```
app_settings {
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL" = "myregistry.azurecr.io"
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME" = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri="https://myapp-kv-az.vault.azure.net/secrets/my-secret-kv-az/redacted)"
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD" = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myapp-kv-az.vault.azure.net/secrets/my-pass-az-pass/redacted)"
}
```

Comment: still getting the same error. "ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://registry.azurecr.io/v2/myApp-webapp/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required"}"

Comment: fixed it. Instead of passing @Microsoft.keyvault(SecretUri="").

I've used data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "myacrServer" {
  name      = "myApp-acr-server-az"
  vault_uri = "https://myApp-kv-az-acr.vault.azure.net/"
}

app_settings {
    "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME" = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.myacrusname.value}"
}

Comment: this means you are getting data from kv in the terraform, not at the webapp

Comment: yeah, now I'm able to retrieve the value from KV. My webapp is up and running :)